# alway display people that liked page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a website with a Like button. When I (or any other user) am is logged in to facebook, he can see a list of some people that liked the page.

However, if the user is not logged to FB, the fb like displays a borind "125 people liked the page".

How can a list of names + photos be displayed ALWAYS?

Thanks

Comment: I checked it out - eg. http://www.askpavel.co.il/ even when I am not loggen in, the left panel show how many people like and some photos...

Comment: Ah - this is a different plugin.  It is not the regular ["like plugin"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not the regular ["like button" plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).  You are looking for the "like box" plugin.  [You can find the documentation and code here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Make sure to enable the "show faces" option so that you see the profile pictures. You can also disable the stream and header to only show the like's.  You can also customize the width and height to fit more pictures in the plugin.